# php regex function and unable to convert JavaScript argument

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, regex

I created a simple test for a function to grab the video id from a youtube url and echo it out. It works fine as is but when I introduce jQuery code in the mix I receive this error `NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument`. The error is commenting the jquery.js file on line 7071. I have no idea what to do or what is exactly causing this. The code is below.

First File

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="url" />

<input type="button" id="press" value="click" />

<div id="return"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" >

    $('#press').click(function () {

$('#url').val();

    $.post('ajax_youtube.php', {url:url}, function(data) {

        $('#return').html(data);

    }); 

    });

</script>
```

Here is the `ajax_youtube.php` file

```
<?php

function get_youtube_url($text) {

$text = preg_replace('~https?://(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be/| youtube\.com\S*[^\w
\-\s])([\w\-]{11})(?=[^\w\-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w]*(?:[\'"][^<>]*>| </a>))[?=&+%\w-]*~ix', 
'$1', $text);

echo $text;

}

$url = $_POST['url'];

get_youtube_url($url);

?>
```

Comment: I think this `$('#url').val();` should be `var url = $('#url').val();`

Comment: Thanks. I feel silly. Post it as the answer since you were the first one to answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to assign `url` to a value, `$('#url').val();` should be `var url = $('#url').val();`